# How to get SPFeatureDefinition for Generic List in sandboxed solution

Tags: list, custom-list, feature-receiver, schema

When creating custom list programatically from schema Add method needs `SPFeatureDefinition` object of the base list used.

> SPListCollection.Add method (String, String, String, String, Int32,
>   String, String, SPFeatureDefinition,
>   SPListTemplate.QuickLaunchOptions)

listInstanceFeatureDefintion

```
Type: Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinition
An object that contains the base definition for the list.
```

How to get that information in `sandbox`, I was only able to find example where `SPFarm.Local.FeatureDefinitions` was used like this

```
SPFeatureDefinitionCollection farmFeatures = SPFarm.Local.FeatureDefinitions;

Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinition genericListInstanceFeatureDefintion =  how to get ?
```

It seems to work with null value also, but was wondering does it have any side effects to leave it null?